# Combining negative character classes in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a string like this:

```
a = 'Somewhere +in+ La-Mancha, in a |place| whose {name} I [do not care] to remember'
```

I want to remove any non-word and non-space characters. The following snippet works as expected:

```
a.gsub(/[^\w\s]/,'')
# => "Somewhere in LaMancha in a place  whose name I do not care to remember"
```

But the following does not work.

```
a.gsub(/[\W\S]/,'')
# => ""
```

Theoretically, both regexes are equivalent, but they don't work in the same way. Does anyone know the reason?

Is it possible to combine negative character classes?

Answer (score 6):

> Theorically, both regexes are equivalent

Not at all.

This is basic school level logic.

- `not (A or B)` (or equivalently, `(not A) and (not B)`)
- `(not A) or (not B)`

are different. Particularly,

- `[^\w\s]` is: not (a word character or a space character).
- `[\W\S]` is: a non-word character or a non-space character.

They are different. For example, a character that is non-word and is a space matches the second regex, but not the first.

> Is it possible to combine negative character classes?

Yes. There is intersection operator `&&` for character classes.

```
/[\W&&\S]/
```

is equivalent to `[^\w\s]`.

Comment: Definitely, /[\W&&\S]/ is the expression I was looking for, but the discussion has been fantastic :)

Comment: I was not familiar with `&&` in a character class so I did a bit of poking around and came upon [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html). I found the example involving Unicode characters especially interesting.

Answer (score 5):

The relationships between the atoms in positive and negative character classes are different. In positive ones, the atoms are ORed (match this OR that), and in the negative character classes, the elements are ANDed (do not match this AND that).

So, `[\W\S]` matches characters other than alphanumeric/underscore, or - if found - also match those that are not equal to whitespace. **Since `\W` matches whitespace and `\S` matches any non-whitespace, this `[\W\S]` matches any character**. That is why `a.gsub(/[\W\S]/,'')` returns an empty string.

As for `[^\w\s]`, it matches any character that is not an alphanumeric/underscore AND that is not a whitespace. Thus, it matches any non-word character and no whitespace characters (a synonym for `[\W&&[^\s]]` construct). See [rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/ZpoV0DtmUH).

*One more illustration*:

`\W` is a generic shorthand character class matching all non-word (or, matching any character other than a "word") character. Now, we want to match all the non-word characters *with the exception of `;`*. A semicolon is a non-word character. What shall we do? We can use the negated character class with the opposite class `\w` - `[^\w]` - and add the `;` to it -> `[^\w;]`. This `[^\w;]` will match any non-word and non-`;` characters.

Comment: I think it is a complicated way to understand negative character classes like that. My understanding is that it is **always `or`**, but the negative `^` applies to the entire content of `[]`.

Comment: @sawa: Let's leave that to SO users/future readers, what is complicated and what not. Actually, I disagree it is basic school level.

Comment: But I gave +1 for pointing out that `[\W\S]` matches any character, which I forgot to point out.

Comment: At least in my country, de Morgan's law is taught at fourth grade (using sets, but without using logic symbols). And fully with symbol, it is taught at tenth grade.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I rarely use the classes and didn't recall on that.

Comment: @Rubén_ic: Just do not *skip* your classes :) See, they teach logics there :)